# How to issue the SLEEP command in Attiny

Tags: attiny, sleep

I want to put an Attiny13 to sleep. In short chapter 7 of the datasheet says you have to do the following:
    set sleep mode
    sleep enable (set SE bit)
    issue SLEEP command

Generally this is done with aid of the 'sleep.h' library and then translates to

```
set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
sleep_enable();
sleep_cpu();
```

If I dont want to use the sleep.h library, the sleep mode and sleep enable are easy to set via 3 bits (SM[1:0] and SE)  but how do I issue the SLEEP command?
If I look how the sleep.h library actually does it, it is defined as `__asm__ __volatile__ ( "sleep" "\n\t" :: );`
That seems odd, do i really have to issue the word 'sleep' somewhere in a program to get the attiny to sleep? Cant I just set a register somewhere?
The Sleep.h library seems like a lot of overhead if i just want to put a chip to sleep

Answer (score 4):

The `asm` instruction allows the entering of assembly directly; in this case, the AVR has an instruction explicitly for putting the microcontroller to sleep. You can't do this with a register - you have to do it by emitting the relevant assembly instruction.

There's no need to do this yourself, however - `sleep.h` is not a library, but a header file that's part of avr-libc, and including it and using it will incur no more overhead than doing it yourself; relevant parts will be inlined by the compiler, and any unused parts of the header file will not end up in the compiled result.